# Disk Management: Not able to make a new volume

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

I am not able successfully make a new volume from unallocated space in disk management.

I will try to explain you all through points and screenshot.

What I did:

1. shrink space from Local Disk (E:) [Before (E:) had 416 Gb)
2. This resulted in unallocated space formation of 392 Gb and 24 Gb remaining in
   (E:).
3. Then, I tried to make all this space a new volume with letter (G:)
4. After doing all settings and clicking finish, a dialog box appeared(see in image)
5. I have a single HDD.

[The dialog which appears after clicking finish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPG6t.jpg)

**Why I am doing this:**

1. My (C:) drive space is running low, so I wanted to extend its space using 25 GB space from (E:) and 25 Gb from (D:), 50 Gb in total.
2. I saw some videos on youtube about how I can do this. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V2vnfsAe0M (please watch to understand what I am trying to do).
3. Initial space--> (C:) drive is 97 Gb, (D:) is 416 Gb, and (E:) is 416 Gb.
4. In result I want three partitions (C:) of 147 Gb,(D:) of 392 Gb, and (E:) of 392 Gb.

**So what should I do? I think that it may cause some problem**

Comment: Can you expand Local Disk E back to its original size?

Comment: You already have four primary partitions on MBR. Do you even want that many partitions? Or do you just want to be able to use that space?

Comment: Are you using MBR or GPT?  Please edit your question to include this very vital and important information.

Comment: MBR can support up to 44 primary partitions - this could be the problem here. We don't know if he uses MBR though, Daniel, and I'm sure OP actually wants that many partitions ... no need to question that.

Comment: @DanielB, I have three partitions only (C:), (D:), and (E:). I just want to move 25 Gb from (E:) _(which was 416 Gb)_ to (C:) drive whose space remaining is very less. Question has been edited, read again.

Comment: @hextech, I want total 3 partions in result, please read question again, it has been edited.

Comment: @hextech, my (C:) drive space remaining is very less. So I watched a video on how can you extend space in C drive. Please watch this video(you will understand) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V2vnfsAe0M .  So I want this 392 Gb unallocated space to be new (E:) drive and move that 25 Gb space to (C:) drive. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: Oops - I meant 4 partitions, not 44.
I've added an answer - take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal here is to expand (C:) drive space, using 25 GB space from (D:) drive and 25 GB from (E:) drive.

- Solution for **Windows 10** below.
- Software needed: **easeUS Partition Master**.

**Precautions before going below for further steps:**

1. Insure that your PC to have regular power supply by battery or UPS because sometimes there can be a power outage, and something can go wrong with your PC. So insure to have some power backup.
2. I  did not lost any data while doing the steps, but you can keep precautions because I do not think if software gives any guarantee for data.

**Steps to do so:**

1. software you need (Download if you do not have): **easeUS Partition Master**. You can download it from its official website. Functions of software we need are free, so no need to buy some plan.
2. Install easeUS Partition Master. Version I used was 14.0 of this software.
3. Go to "Disk Management" by right clicking on start.
4. Shrink amount of volume from (D:) and (E:) that you need to add in (C:) drive. (1 GB consists of 1024 MB to be accurate, use calculator)
5. Close everything running on your windows 10.
6. Open **easeUS Partition Master 14.0** software *(or version that you have)*.
7. Right click on (E:) drive and click move/change. Then, drag the partition to extremely right without changing its space,*(So that unallocated space moves to left)* and click OK.
8. Do same as above to (D:) drive moving it to right, so that all unallocated space is together and to left of (D:) drive, ***i.e. to the right of (C:) drive***.
9. Then, find "execute" button somewhere near the top left corner. Click it to execute the operations you have chosen. Some of the times a dialog box may appear asking to shut down the Pc and restart in master boot mode, do not worry as it is necessary and so **click ok**. It will take some time for process completion depending on storage speed of your pc and on the amount of data you have.
10. After your Pc has been restarted go for further steps below:
11. Go to "Disk Management" again. You can see there all your unallocated space to the right of (C:) drive.
12. Right click on (C:) drive >> Click extend volume >> choose maximum space in wizard menu >> Do not change any other setting and keep clicking next-next-next and then finish.
13. Operation may take some time.
14. After operation gets completed, you can see that all your unallocated space has been added to (C:) drive and it has been extended.
15. You have successfully extended your (C:) drive space.

Answer (score 1):

The goal here is to expand the C partition.

With the windows disk partition manager, it's only possible to expand partitions if there's free space next to these partitions. In other words, you need free space after partition C - or between partition C and partition D.

The process in the video made this possible by **deleting** the partition that was next to the C partition. So in your case, you would have to:

1. Delete the D partition and then expand C partition with windows disk partition manager
2. Use other software to help you **move** **partitions** around (like AOMEI or gparted) (not sure if you can achieve this with using `diskpart` utility)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but problem is that I want to give 25 Gb from (E:) and 25 Gb from (D:) to (C:) and to have three partitions in result. Because I want three partitions, one for software, one for my data(data about serious things), and one for non-serious things like movies, songs etc.

Comment: I understand the problem - but you cannot do it in windows disk partition manager without deleting the D and E partitions, or moving partitions around with some other software. Your problem is different than the one in the video you linked.

Comment: I am not able to make any new volume also, dunno why. But thanks so much bro for guiding me. But I have found a way or you can say hack to do what i want by using EaseUS partition master. See my solution that I have added to my question, so that it may help others. Thanks again.